# Angular 6 - Collapse mobile menu on click

Tags: jquery, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular6

I have a static page in angular 6 that have some tabs, how can i make the mobile menu collapse when a element is clicked? I need some thing like this jQuery code (i can't use jQuery).

```
$('.navbar-nav>li>a').on('click', function() {
  $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

My nav menu code is bellow.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav w-100">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-check mb-3"></i> Finance legal tax and HR
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-check mb-3"></i> Information technology
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-check mb-3"></i> Risk and cybersecurity
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the click-event-handler together with a component property.

```
export class MyComponent{
 collpaseMenu: boolean = false;
}
```

and in your template:

```
<button (click)="collapseMenu = !collapseMenu"></button>

<ul class="navbar-nav w-100" [hidden]="collapseMenu">...</ul>
```

Comment: I need that the mobile menu collapse, not hide. but thanks!

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#collapsehide , Bootstrap is doing the same. Maybe it's not the right position and you have to hide the <li>-Elements